Keyboard Inputs Blocked from Mouse
I have a Logitech mouse with programmable buttons. The configuration is stored in firmware, so there is no need to configure anything with the operating system. When I push one of these buttons, a keyboard sequence is sent from the mouse to the machine.
On current Windows and in previous versions of Ubuntu (focal), these buttons worked without any issues. However, after upgrading to jammy (22.04), these inputs aren't processed by the operating system. This leads me to believe that there is some sort of security policy blocking the mouse from emulating a keyboard.
How can I diagnose and address this issue so that the keyboard commands sent from the mouse are processed as was the case on previous versions of Ubuntu?

It seems the culprit may once again be Wayland. It became the default display system in 21.04, so your upgrade to Focal (22.04) meant a switch from X.org graphics to Wayland. You can try switching back to X.org and see if that lets you use the mouse buttons again.

I'm using X.org, actually, so I don't think this is related to Wayland. ps aux | grep -i wayland returns nothing, so definitely not running Wayland.
